# mutually recursive types in haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am a new learner in  Haskell, the notion of Mutually recursive types confused me a lot.

Here is an example:

```
data BoolExpr
     = BoolConst Bool
     | BoolOp BoolOp BoolExpr BoolExpr
     | ConpOp CompOp IntExpr IntExpr
```

Why here are two `BoolOp` and `CompOp`?

I  know that the first `BoolOp` is a data constructor, but how about the second `BoolOp`?

Comment: Where is this code from? It'll be easier to explain with more context.

Comment: I don't see mutually recursive types; I just see a single recursive data type, `BoolExpr`.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right that the first `BoolOp` is a [constructor](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#algebraic-data-types); the second says that the constructor takes a value of type `:: BoolOp`.  The full type is:

```
BoolOp :: BoolOp -> BoolExpr -> BoolExpr -> BoolExpr
```

So I'd expect there's some code like this lying around:

```
data BoolOp = BoolAnd  |  BoolOr  |  BoolXor
```

So to use this constructor, you'd need to give it a `BoolOp` and two `BoolExpr`s:

```
myBoolExpr :: BoolExpr
myBoolExpr = BoolOp  BoolOr  (BoolConst True)  (BoolConst False)
```

Comment: @Kevin quick, say it fives times fast while holding your tongue!

Comment: @MattFenwick so i can change the name of BoolOp, can i ? like: 
data BoolExpr = a BoolOp BoolExpr BoolExpr. is that correct?

Comment: @user1611996 you *can* change it, but constructors have to start with a capital letter, so `a` won't work.